# Discord bot sends many questions in dm at a time without waiting for the user to respond

Tags: discord.py

I need my bot to send questions to users for them to answer when the user writes a command.

but the bot ended up sending 2 or 3 questions at a time randomly without waiting for the user to answer.

[Image that shows the output of the bot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QNiK.png)
which makes the value of **RP N** = "Name:"

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
            return
    
    if message.content.startswith('!add'):
        
        await message.author.send(
                "``Fill in the blanks by replying, then the bot will give a confirmation message.``")
    
        for element in report:
            await message.author.send("**"+element+"**")
            response = await client.wait_for('message')
            var(response.content)
```

**report** is the list of the questions

**var** is list.append

**Edit:** I have tried to add check argument.

```py
def check(m):
        return m.content != element in report
```

And that didn't work, still having the same issue.

Comment: try to add a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Client.wait_for) in the wait_for maybe that is your

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: This isn't the full code, I'll upload it if it helps. I have tried to add check but didn't know how to set it up correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem.

```py
def check(m):
          return message.author == m.author and isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel)
```

Answer (score -3):

To delay commands I suggest using `time.sleep()` [TimeSleep](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-time-sleep) if you don't want it to respond so fast you can put a little delay.

Comment: `time` blocks code in this case, it would be better to use `import asyncio` and `asyncio.sleep` instead